# jQuery animate a div moving around a other divs edges (loop)

Tags: jquery, animation, move

How can i make div moving around a other div his edges? Just like a moving border that is animated moving around the edges.

Comment: Please try with following code and let me know it is working as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var h = $(".container").height() - $(".move").height();
var w = $(".container").width() - $(".move").width();

setInterval(function(){
$(".move").animate({left: w+'px', top:'0px'});
$(".move").animate({left: w+'px', top: h+'px'});
$(".move").animate({left: '0px', top: h+'px'});
$(".move").animate({left: '0px', top: '0px'});
},500);
});
```

```css
.move {
background:#98bf21;height:50px;width:50px;position:absolute;"
}
.container { position:relative; width:500px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="move"></div>
```

Comment: This is what i needed thnx!